# How to get reduce time interval from timepicker selected values in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app ,In this i created timepicker and i want to reduce the time of timepicker selected value by 6 hours (i.e 06:00 like hh:mm). Following is the code which i used.
Example:
if user pick 12:30 pm then it will have to show 06:30pm in textview.
How do i do this?

```
//java file
public class ProfileActivity4 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView textView;
    private EditText eddate, edtime;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    Button btn;
    EditText edname,edaddress;
    Button ptime, pdate;

    TextView tvsname, tvsprice;
    NumberPicker numberPicker;
    TextView textview1,textview2;
    Integer temp;
    String pname, paddress, email, sname, sprice;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    Spinner spinnerPick;
    TextView tdpicktime;
    String picktime;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile4);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // back button pressed

                Intent i = new Intent(ProfileActivity4.this, List_Activity1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //    initNavigationDrawer();

        //Initializing textview
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        edname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_pname);
        edaddress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_add);
        tvsname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
        tvsprice=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2_price);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        spinnerPick=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_picktime);
        tdpicktime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_picktime);

        //    ArrayAdapter<String> sAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rides));
        ArrayAdapter<String> sAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.flighttype));
        spinnerPick.setAdapter(sAdapter1);

        spinnerPick.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                picktime = spinnerPick.getSelectedItem().toString();

                }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        eddate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_date);
        edtime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_time);

        ptime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ptime);
        pdate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_pdate);

        ptime.setOnClickListener(this);
        pdate.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        final String name = i.getStringExtra("company_name");
        // displaying selected product name
        tvsname.setText(name);

        String price = i.getStringExtra("sedan_price");
        // displaying selected product name
        tvsprice.setText(price);

        textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1_amount);
        // textview2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_seats);

        final int foo = Integer.parseInt(price);
        textview1.setText(String.valueOf(foo));

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
                String email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "Not Available");
                textView.setText(email);

                if (loggedIn) {

                    submitForm();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity4.this, Confirm_Activity4.class);
                    intent.putExtra("company_name", name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void submitForm() {

        String pname = edname.getText().toString();
        String paddress = edaddress.getText().toString();
        String sname = textview1.getText().toString();
        String time = edtime.getText().toString();
        String date = eddate.getText().toString();
        String email= textView.getText().toString();

        new SignupActivity3(this).execute(pname,paddress,sname,time,date,email);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == pdate) {

            // Get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            eddate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (v == ptime) {

            // Get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                      edtime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);

            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize new calendar object with timepicker selected date.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // this would default to now
    calendar.setTime(/*selected timepicker time*/); //or with epoch (long value like 1472554134000 with calendar.setTimeInMillis())
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -6)
```

if you are using 12-Hour clock then use **Calendar.HOUR** else **Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY**

Comment: i am using 24 hours clock

Comment: calendar.setTime(edtime); At this line it shows the error like 'calender cannot be apply to java.lang.string'

Comment: you cant pass a EditText object, it requires a Date object, construct a Date object in **onTimeSet** then perform your manipulation on this created Date object.

Comment: final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -6);
            Date picktime= c.getTime();
           tvpick.setText((CharSequence) picktime);

Comment: I have done the above code but still its not working

Comment: the code is works fine for current picker date and time,but it dose not show the result for manualy added picker date and time.

Comment: an epoch is a counter from 1970, so cant have only time, you have to set date also and make sure you have correct date object unless it will give you wrong value.

Comment: how can i check this?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime.parse( "12:30" ).minusHours( 6 ).toString()
```

## java.time

Use modern date-time classes in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project, an Android adaptation of [the back-port](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) of the [java-time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

You inputs and outputs happen to be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. These standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes for parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern; Parse directly.

The [`LocalTime`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "12:30" );
LocalTime earlier = lt.minusHours( 6 );
String output = earlier.toString();
```